# *ngFor with multiple arrays

Tags: angular, ionic2, ngfor

I have an object data which contains 2 arrays(photo and comments come from server) and I'd like to show them with *ngFor but ngFor shows only array types.

Here is my **Ts** file:

```ts
this.comments=[];
// ...
  .subscribe((data) => {
    this.comments= data.comments;
    console.log("data: ", data);
    this.commentPhoto = data.Photo; 
    // I don't want to create another array 
    // I want to make commentPhoto and comments array in 1 Array to show them.
```

**HMTL**

```html
<ion-row *ngFor="let cm of comments">

  <ion-col col-2 style="border:1px solid grey;">
    <img src="{{cm.photo}}" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
  </ion-col>

  <ion-col col-10 style="border:1px solid grey;">
    {{cm}}
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

How can I do it in 1 array
data photo 
[image]
Thank you.

Comment: can you show us some part of your data (Photo and comments)? You can combine these two into one, or use a pipe to combine, but there has to be a relation between those two.

Comment: At least I am having trouble understanding how you would like that this "new" array should look like? Could you present that, and also what you have tried to solve this, and where you are facing an issue in your code.

Answer (score 8):

I think you want to show both **array** from one `*ngFor`. I can see your **data** which are having two **Arrays**: `comment` and `photo`.

You can achieve it two ways, One is: Use `index`:

```
this.comments= data.comment;
this.commentPhoto = data.Photo;
```

Here if both **array's length** is ***same*** and **order** also, then try this:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let cm of comments; let i = index">
  <ion-col col-2 style="border:1px solid grey;">
    <img src="{{commentPhoto[i]}}" style="width:45px;height:45px;">  // For photos
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-10 style="border:1px solid grey;">
    {{cm}}
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Second, Combined both array as object in one place before rendering in **template**:

```
data: [{comment: "...", photo: ""},..]
```

then render this. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I did with the same solution I wish I saw this soluion early.Thank you for your nice answer  and work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to modify the result data. Make a model let's say `PhotoData`.

```csharp
public class PhotoData
{
    public Image Photo { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

And pass it to your TS file or service call.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:

```ts
/**
  * Function to return an array of keys of an object
  * @param itemObj
  * @returns {string[]}
 */
dataKeys(itemObj): Array<string> {
    return Object.keys(itemObj);
}
```

```html
<ion-row *ngFor="let key of dataKeys">

  <ion-col col-2 style="border:1px solid grey;" *ngFor="let item of dataKeys[key]">
    <img src="{{item}}" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
  </ion-col>

</ion-row>
```

Comment: In your 1st ngFor what is dataKeys referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your all answers, I solved it like this.

**TS**

```
 .subscribe((data) => {
  this.comments= data;
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let cm of comments.context; let i=index">

 <ion-col col-2 style="border:1px solid grey;">
  <img src="{{cm.photo[i]}}" style="width:45px;height:45px;">
 </ion-col>

<ion-col col-10 style="border:1px solid grey;">
    {{cm}}
 </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Here photo and context are the Arrays which are included in the data  Ts file

Thank you for all.